# salesforcedx behind a corporate proxy that intercepts https traffic

Tags: salesforcedx

I have installed git, nodejs and salesforcedx successfully. I have configured my proxy in all applications. The proxy intercepts all https traffic. I do have access to the root certificate, but I am not very familiar with how these work and have not installed it in any certificate stores (do I need to?).

I can successfully use salesforcedx like so:

```
sfdx force --help
```

I can also use npm to download packages fine, and I can use git to clone repositories. All of these required me to set my http proxy and https proxy, and ssl verify to false.

However, when I try and run sfdx update I get the following error:

```
Get https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/sfdxstable/manifest.json: Proxy Access Denied
```

Can someone please tell me which proxy settings this line would refer to? I am having difficulty identifying why the update command is struggling to get the manifest.json file, when I can run sfdx force --help fine.

Comment: `sfdx force --help` won't be making any API callouts, so it wouldn't care about proxy settings. Or at least I wouldn't expect it to.

Comment: Have you seen [Use the Salesforce CLI from Behind a Company Firewall or Web Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm)?

Comment: Also, what happens if you request https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/sfdxstable/manifest.json in a browser configured to use the same proxy? I get a json file with paths to .tar.xz files.

Comment: sfdx force --help did not work until I configured my proxy. I initially configured my proxy using the instructions mentioned by Daniel Ballinger. This got sfdx working to a point, but I cannot perform the sfdx update or Authorise against a DEVHUB (which also seems to a proxy issue - but may not be related to this so keeping it separate).

Comment: Is the proxy messing with the contents or selectively blocking URLs? Try loading the problem URLs directly in a browser.

Comment: I just pinged someone from the product team.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identified the issue. I had set the environment variable HTTP_PROXY in the Environment Variables section of my windows System Properties to

```
http://webproxyaddress:8080/
```

instead of

```
http://user:pwd@webproxyaddress:8080/
```

I had set these correctly everywhere else, but since I was on a windows machine I somehow missed going back and checking my systems environment variable. Turns out this is a really important step!

See also: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm

Comment: You may also need to set `HTTPS_PROXY` to the same value if the proxy intercepts all traffic.

Comment: Thanks dragon788. You are correct, I did have to set that one as well.

Comment: See also https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/241082/62423 if you get warnings about a SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN with a fix for that.