# "ERROR: self signed certificate in certificate chain." on SFDX force:auth:web:login

Tags: salesforcedx

Could not find the issue hence asking, after updating SFDx to v43. When trying to connect to a sandbox i am getting -

> "ERROR:  self signed certificate in certificate chain"

I have run below commands but it didn't resolved the issue:

1. set `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`
2. set `HTTPS_PROXY= {https proxy}`

there are no other process running on port 1717 on my machine , Is there any way possible to get past this without using the CA signed certs?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191591/sfdx-shows-self-signed-cert-in-chain-when-trying-to-authorise-or-list-behind-ssl maybe this could help?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Stas, I had a look but it seems to be requiring certs. I was able to make it work by following below steps.

1. Set Windows Env Variable NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED with Value =0.
2. Log Off and Log in to windows

Ideally it's the similar to command - set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 but somehow it didn't worked for me but worked for my colleague.

Comment: Thanks Amit, this worked!

Comment: This worked for me as well - which was in a government pod (fedramp?) and helped us get around the issues.  Thanks!

Comment: Could we do this somehow for the vscode project alone versus an environment variable?

Comment: Thank you Amit. Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Amit, this worked for me