# VSCode for Salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, trailhead, vs-code

I am trying to connect VSCode with my SF org(a trailhead org) and I get to the SF login page and then when I try to login, I get the following error:
[image: VSCode error]

I am not sure why this is happening but I believe it's caused because I am trying to do this behind a company firewall.

I have tried killing the 1717 port and then re-run, but I still face the same issue.

Comment: Getting the Salesforce CLI to work from behind a firewall or proxy can be challenging. See [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm) for the necessary config steps. What would be more helpful (but probably not much) than the screenshot from your browser, is the `Output ` panel in VS Code when you try to authorize to the org. It can also be helpful to run the command directly from the `cmd` command line - the `sfdx force:org:connect -a [alias]` command.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response. This is what I get in my VSCode when I am trying to login: 'Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org
16:32:19.459 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
ERROR running force:auth:web:login:  self signed certificate in certificate chain
16:32:24.903 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 1' . I am new to this so if I should provide more details, please let me know and I will do my best to provide them.

Comment: There are answers [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191591/sfdx-shows-self-signed-cert-in-chain-when-trying-to-authorise-or-list-behind-ssl) and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236875/error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-sfdx-forceauthweblo) that may help with that error.