# Cannot authorise a salesforce org in VS Code due to certificate error

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, certificates, ssl

I cannot authorise a salesforce org in VS Code.  I am prompted to login, but then I get this error:

```
ERROR running auth:web:login:  Invalid client credentials. Verify the OAuth client secret and ID. Error authenticating with auth code due to: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

A couple of points:

- It's the same error regardless of which org I am connecting to.
- It's the same error if I am connecting to prod or sandbox
- It's the same error if I use login.salesforce.com or the  production url domain
- It's the same error for other users trying to authorise an org

We had issues with data loader last week and it was related to SSL Decryption so we needed to update java cacerts file with signed certs to fix the issue.  I am guessing this is also related to certs, but I have no idea what certs VS Code uses or where it references them. Does anyone have any insight?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: or a corporate proxy?

Comment: If either are true, you can follow this article which will help you set your custom CA Certs files which will allow you to import your intermediate certificate and solve this issue https://medium.com/@jonatascastro12/understanding-self-signed-certificate-in-chain-issues-on-node-js-npm-git-and-other-applications-ad88547e7028

Comment: If you can make it work from the command-line, you should be able to wrangle VS Code: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236875/error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-sfdx-forceauthweblo/