# Error authenticating with auth code due to: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I am getting below error when try to authorize any org in the VS code.

> Error authenticating with auth code due to: self signed certificate in
> certificate chain

After spending significant amount of time I got only one solution on the internet which is to set the below in cmd

> set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

restarted my system but nothing is working for me.

Could someone please help me to resolve the same?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191591/sfdx-shows-self-signed-cert-in-chain-when-trying-to-authorise-or-list-behind-ssl might work

Comment: Would you please help how to use NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS it is not very clear how to use this to resolve my issue