# Install the Command Line Interface (CLI) salesforceDX

Tags: trailhead, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I have installed CLI as per the guidelines and I have setup the environment variable as well. Then I entered `sfdx` command in command prompt as well as in  GitBash, but it's not giving the proper response as showing in [Set Up Salesforce DX Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/sfdx_get_started/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_setup_dx). I am getting the response as below, could you please help me to resolve this issue.
​

```
$ sfdx
panic: Get https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-cli/channels/stable/windows-x64: dial tcp: lookup developer.salesforce.com: getaddrinfow: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x6632a0, 0xc042008780)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1af
main.must(0x7b92c0, 0xc042008780)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/io.go:115 +0x63
main.GetUpdateManifest(0x6a4875, 0x7, 0x6a3c0d, 0x3, 0x7b92c0)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/install.go:104 +0x272
main.GetUpdateManifest(0x6a4875, 0x7, 0x6a3c0d, 0x3, 0x0)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/install.go:102 +0x2f4
main.Install()
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/install.go:33 +0x100
main.main()
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/main.go:18 +0x3a
```

Comment: Just curious : Any idea why you are running Ubuntu, yet 'windows-x64' appears in the URL?

Comment: No idea. This has happened in in my office desktop. The same guidelines i followed to install in  my personal desktop it's giving absolutely proper response . Still i don't know the reason exactly why it is happening in my office desktop.

Answer (score 1):

> This has happened in in my office desktop. The same guidelines i followed to install in my personal desktop it's giving absolutely proper response . Still i don't know the reason exactly why it is happening in my office desktop

The difference is probably one of the following:

- Firewall
- Proxy Server
- Environment Variables

> To address this issue, run these commands from your terminal or Windows command prompt, replacing username:pwd with your web proxy username and password. If your proxy doesn’t require these values, omit them. Also replace proxy.company.com:8080 with the URL and port of your company proxy.

```
npm config set https-proxy https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set proxy https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
```

> Then set the HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment variable to the full URL of the proxy. For example, on UNIX:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
```

> On a Windows machine:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
```

> If you set the proxy environment variable, and you still see error messages, it’s possible that your proxy requires an extra certificate authority (CA). Ask your IT department where to find or download the certificates.
>
> Set this environment variable to point to the CA file: `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`.

**References**

- [Environment Variables | Salesforce DX Developer Guide | Salesforce Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_env_variables.htm)
- [salesforcedx behind a corporate proxy that intercepts https traffic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191088/)